# Add Existing Story's to Features - Azure DevOps (VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

Is it possible to add existing Azure DevOps (VSTS) board story's to a new feature?

I have hundreds of story's in the backlog and want to start adding them to new features, but I can't see any way of doing that?
Look like you can only create new stories with features.

Comment: Looks like you are using some tool. What tool?

Comment: Sorry about that......Azure DevOps (VSTS)

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "Mapping" Right Pane on the backlog:
[image]
And then you can select all the user stories and drop them to the related features.